# Mysql Db replication

Tags: mysql, database, replication

I have the following setup:

3 servers, B1, B2, B3. A database from B1 is being replicated to B2. B1 is master and B2 is slave. Now, I want an another database from B2 to be replicated to B3.

I need to know if an already configured slave (for some other server) can act as master for a different server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, every server can be a master and a slave. The most basic example of this is having two servers that are both master and slaves for the other.
The details are in the [mysql manual.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-cluster-replication-multi-master.html)
Your scenario is not that hard, because you are only going in one direction. Having the B3 server push data back to B1 would be more complex, but if all the other servers are just slaves and new data is basically coming in to B1 then it's not too difficult to manage.